# Trying to add user control to form crashes Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I created a `UserControl` called `Switch`.
I built my project and this UC successfully shown in my toolbox.
So I tried to add it to my `frmMain` by dragging it to the form. But at this moment, Visual Studio always shows an error message:

> A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

After clicking OK, `devenv.exe` crashes.

I have to mention, that I have another user control in the same namespace and folder as `Switch`. This UC works fine.

This is the code of my `Switch` user control:

```cs
public partial class Switch : UserControl
{
    private Rectangle switchRectangle;
    private int xOn = 0; // switchRectangle x position, when switch is on
    private int xOff = 0; // switchRectangle x position, when switch is off

    private Color SwitchColor = Color.Black;
    private Color OuterRectangleColor = Color.DarkGray;

    private Color InnerRectangleColor
    {
        get { return this.On ? Color.DodgerBlue : InnerRectangleColor; }
    }
    public bool On { get; set; }
    public Switch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReloadSwitchRectangle();
        xOn = this.Width - switchRectangle.Width;
    }

    private void Switch_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
        // Create inner rectangle, on every side by 2px smaller than ClientRectangle
        const int amountToDecrease = 2;
        Rectangle innerRectangle = new Rectangle(this.ClientRectangle.X + amountToDecrease, this.ClientRectangle.Y + amountToDecrease,
            this.ClientRectangle.Width - amountToDecrease * 2, this.ClientRectangle.Height - amountToDecrease * 2);
        ReloadSwitchRectangle();

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(OuterRectangleColor), this.ClientRectangle); // Draw outer rectangle
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(InnerRectangleColor), innerRectangle); // Fill inner rectangle
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SwitchColor), switchRectangle);
    }

    private void ReloadSwitchRectangle()
    {
        int x = this.On ? xOn : xOff;
        switchRectangle = new Rectangle(x, 0, this.Width / 5, this.Height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
private Color InnerRectangleColor
{
    get { return this.On ? Color.DodgerBlue : InnerRectangleColor; }
}
```

You have infinite recursion here when `this.On` is set to false.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Now I get it. I wanted to write OuterRectangleColor, instead of InnerRectangleColor :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sriram Sakthivel, I solved my problem like this:

```
private Color InnerRectangleColor
{
    get { return this.On ? Color.DodgerBlue : OuterRectangleColor; }
}
```